# Find $A^n$ for n=0,1, and 3: Languages and Finite State Machines

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, automata, formal-languages, finite-automata

The question is:

Let $A$={11,00}.

Find $A^n$ for n=0,1, and 3.

Would i be right in thinking that

$A^0$ = {λ}
$A^1$ = {11,00}
$A^3$ = {111111,111100,110011,110000,000011,000000,001100,001111}.

if not, please could you help point me in the right drection?

Comment: Assuming that $A^n$ refers to the concatenation product, your answers are correct.

Comment: What's up with this question?  It's been posted several times in the last day, most recently [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779305/let-a-11-00-find-an-for-n-0-1-3).  Is it from a contest?

Comment: its from a piece of work, that not many people can understand. and the answers from this site are not particularly helpful, apart from @BrianM.Scott